# NCP12400 ROPP (overpower protection)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, controller

[image: typial schematic from datasheet for NCP12400]

This picture is a typical application circuit in the datasheet of NCP12400 flyback controller IC. What does the ROPP in the red circle mean and how does it work?

Some people say it is used to filter out noise, while others say it is used for overpower protection.

[Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/ncp12400-d.pdf) download from onsemi:
https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/ac-dc-power-conversion/offline-controllers/NCP12400

Comment: The over-power protection feature is explained in the linked datasheet at page #36. Is there a specific part of this description, you do not understand? Or what do you need help with in particular?

Comment: What do you mean by overpower?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known fact that a converter designed to deliver a certain power at low line delivers much higher power in high-line conditions. For instance, should you calculate your components values for a flyback operated in universal mains, from 85 to 265 V rms, then, considering the valley voltage in the rectified bulk capacitor voltage, it is very likely that the true minimum operating voltage is 60-70 V at full load from a 85-V rms input and the converter should deliver its nominal power at that low value. If you then supply the same converter from a 370-V rail, the maximum power it can deliver before its protection trips will be significantly increased. See the below typical chart excerpted from my [APEC 2011](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf) seminar:

[image]

You see that the protection trips at 46 W at low line while the converter can deliver up to 63 W before it stops at high line.

This *overpower* phenomenon can be an issue for safety reasons since you need to dimension you components to withstand a short-circuit current abnormally-higher than what the converter was designed for in the first place. Ac-dc adapters manufacturers also need to ensure the plastic enclosure resists in case of failure (potential fire hazard) and having too high a power imposes the adoption of higher-grade materials, hampering the BOM cost. The standard defining these limits is called *[limited power source](https://www.cui.com/blog/overview-of-limited-power-source-lps-requirements)* (LPS) test.

There are several explanations to this current runaway at different line levels:

- in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM), the propagation delay of the turn-off chain (the CS comparator, the internal logic blocs and the drive path to the MOSFET), delays the effective turn-off time of the transistor and the primary current severely overshoots at high line.
- in continuous conduction mode (CCM), the on-time reduces at high line and gives longer time for demagnetizing the inductor (in fixed-frequency operation), pushing the converter towards DCM. At constant peak current operation (short circuit condition, open loop), the valley current reduces and more energy is conveyed cycle by cycle.

I have covered this issue in 4-part series of [articles](https://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1010/articles/H2PowerToday1010_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) I published in [How2Power](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/index.php). There are plenty of options to compensate the converter and provide *over-power protection* or OPP. The adopted principle behind available solutions is shown below:

[image]

You want the maximum peak current limit to reduce as the input voltage increases. You can do that by directly sensing the input voltage, observe the auxiliary winding etc. In the NPC12400, there is a dedicated high-voltage pin so it is easy to infer the input bias voltage and either reduce the peak value or build a dc offset on the current-sense information:

[image]

In the NCP12400, a dc current is injected into the CS pin and the amount of dc offset is adjusted by the resistance \$R_{OPP}\$. Of course, it is recommended to add a bit of capacitance at the CS pin (100-200 pF) which improves noise immunity at turn-on. \$R_{OPP}\$ and this capacitor must be closely located to the controller.